# Calling one powershell script from another with named parameters and whitespaces in path

Tags: powershell

I have already checked the possible duplicates of this question but I was not able to fix my problem with the given answers.

I have a script install.ps1 with one named parameter -settingsFile

```
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$settingsFile
    )
    Write-Host "calling $PSCommandPath with settings file $settingsFile"
    If (!(Test-Path $settingsFile)){
        Write-Host "cannot load settings[ $settingsFile ], aborting "
        exit
    }
...
...
```

From another powershell script I want to call this, but the given $settingsFile will not be found. 
Here is the caller script

```
    Write-Host "BEGIN-------------------------------------------------------------"

    $configFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath((Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "..\install-data\settings.json"))
    Write-Host ""$configFile""
    If (Test-Path $configFile){
        Write-Host "config found"
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "config not found"
    }

    $argument = "-settingsFile=""$configFile"""
    Write-Host "$argument"
    $installFps = $($PSScriptRoot + "\scripts\install-fps\install-fps.ps1")
    Write-Host """$installFps""" $argument
    Write-Host "case 1: $installFps $argument"
    & $installFps $argument
    Write-Host "END-------------------------------------------------------------"
```

And here the output

```
    BEGIN-------------------------------------------------------------
    C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json
    config found
    -settingsFile="C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json"
    "C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\scripts\install-fps\install-fps.ps1" -settingsFile="C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json"
    case 1: C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\scripts\install-fps\install-fps.ps1 -settingsFile="C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json"
    calling C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\scripts\install-fps\install-fps.ps1 with settings file -settingsFile="C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json"
    cannot load settings[ -settingsFile="C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json" ], aborting
    END-------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I call the script manually from the powershell command line it works, but when I am using it with this script it does not work. The settingsFile does exist, this I can ensure. It seems that my parameter is not correctly transported into the install.ps1 script, because in my log out I can see the the complete string "-settingsFile="C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json" will be transported, not only the filepath "C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json" I need to add always the double quotes because of the possible whitespace in the path.

I have tried several approaches but does not work.

Comment: You could try escaped quotes nstead of triple quotes: ```$argument = "-settingsFile=`"$configFile`""```

Comment: Tried it but resolved in the same result

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you are entering the parmeter:

```
$argument = "-settingsFile=""$configFile"""
```

`settingsFile` is a a Named parameter but you are including an `=` between the param name and value, which is incorrect syntax.

This is causing powershell to interpret it as a single string of `-settingsFile="C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json"` and sending this to the parameter at position 1.

Which is like calling this:

```
-settingsFile '-settingsFile="C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json"'
```

This is shown by the param name appearing in the error message:

> cannot load settings[ **-settingsFile="C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json"** ], aborting

It's easy to fix, remove the `=`:

```
$argument = "-settingsFile ""$configFile"""
```

Comment: I changed it like you said but its still not working. The log output is: cannot load settings[ -settingsFile "C:\Program Files\PaperDynamix\install-data\settings.json" ], aborting  So its still interpreted as one parameter but now without the equal sign. Any idea?

Comment: Without knowing what's going on in `install-fps.ps1` I can't diagnose any further, can you update your question with this please.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has decided that your settingsFile variable has the value 'settingsFile="C:\Program Files\foo\install-data\settings.json"'.  This will be because of the equals sign.  It's treating it as a positional parameter instead of a named one.

Try replacing the equals sign with a colon or space.

```
$argument = "-settingsFile:""$configFile"""

$argument = "-settingsFile ""$configFile"""
```